# How long human can survive with just drinking water everyday

Tags: human-biology, death

Can humans live without eating food, just by drinking water?  How long can we survive just by drinking water everyday?

Comment: 116 "Singh finally heeded a resolution of the Congress party and the request of his father, ending ended his 116-day hunger strike on 5 October 1929"
You can see this on: link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagat_Singh In section: "Hunger strike and Lahore conspiracy case" last paragraph

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About 52 to 74 days according to [`hunger strike` wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunger_strike#Medical_view).

This wiki page bases its data on [8 persons who died due to hunger strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1981_Irish_hunger_strike#Participants_who_died_on_hunger_strike):
Days survived by each person: 66, 59, 61, 61, 61, 46, 71, 73, 62, 60.

Comment: Where does the 74 come from? The highest referenced number there is 73. Did you get 74 from another source or was that just a typo?

Comment: @RhysW: Last line of Medical View says: `There are examples of hunger strikers dying after 52 to 74 days of strike.`

Comment: nice find... I imagine the average is a bit lower than this, but the record kind of tells you how long we can endure without food if we're well hydrated and not otherwise stressed.

Comment: This timeframe is similar to one mentioned in malnutrition lectures I've had

Answer (score 6):

This [would vary a LOT depending on the amount of stored fat, previous diet, the weather and even the water drunk](http://mostextreme.org/longest_without_food.php).  Weeks though there is a good chance that a [loss of electrolytes can cause health problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_fasting).  (that's why I mention the water you drink, because many bottled water brands and wells have a bit of salt in them.)

Its hard to say from anecdotal experience. There are claims of 3 weeks being easy, but a medical study would be unethical because of the risks posed to the subjects.

Answer (score 3):

You can remember this easily as the rule of threes:

You can survive:

- 3 minutes without air. (death by asphyxiation)
- 3 hours without shelter (death by hypothermia, heatstroke).
- 3 days without water. (death by dehydration)
- 3 weeks without food. (death by starvation)

Going beyond those guidelines will generally do you permanent damage.

Further reading: http://www.wildernesscollege.com/basic-survival-skills.html

Comment: Hi cpendlebury, here at Biology.SE we like answers to reference the claims they make.  For more information on this, see [meta](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/294/should-we-always-ask-for-references).

Comment: Noted and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

[**1 year and 17 days only on water and electrolytes.**](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2012/07/24/3549931.htm)

Actually, he went water only for about 75 days *(read that elsewhere, can't remember)* and then they supplemented his water only diet with [electrolytes](http://www.medicinenet.com/electrolytes/article.htm). *He's done it under medical supervision and gained 7 KG in 5 years after the fast. So the weight does stay off (obviously, if you go and stay into a healthier diet).*

Comment: "*He did not eat any food, but the staff gave him yeast for the first 10 months and multi-vitamins every day. Potassium is essential for the proper working of the heart, and when his potassium levels got a little low around the 100-day mark, he was given potassium tablets for about 70 days.*"  Certainly not **just** water.

Comment: @Amory Well, if it's any consolation, he pushed further than anyone mentioned here on water alone. I've also read this in a research PDF and they mention at least 75 days on water alone. If I'll find it again, I'll link it here.