# How much time can a human survive only drinking water and eating sugar?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, nutrition

If a person only drinks water and eats glucose, how long could they survive before getting any symptoms? When would the damage become irreversible? When would that person die from lack of minerals, proteins and vitamins? Also, can this "process" be sped up by drinking distilled (pure) water?

Comment: You may want to look at so called "Muselmann" created in german concentration camps, becasue their diet consisted of nothing but carbohydrates(vegetable broth and bread) and water.  Protein deficiency seems to be the most important factor.

Comment: According to WP, symptoms of vitamin C deficiency (scurvy) will appear after 1 month.

Comment: @John Actually there's at least one study I'm familiar with where a 27yo male fasted for 382 days with no ill effects (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2495396/). He had vitamin and nutrient supplements but no protein. I'm pretty sure the cause of death will be related to a vitamin deficiency.

Comment: What about vitamin deficiencies that weaken your immune system and tend to lead to death from infection? Would those count?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8279/how-long-human-can-survive-with-just-drinking-water-everyday (but without the sugar)

Comment: The type of sugar matters a lot in this case, since muscovado, jaggery or other non-centrifugal cane sugars contain vitamins and minerals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscovado#Nutrition).

Comment: @arboviral fasting does not mean zero calories, you have to look at the type of fasting, many are only a restriction on on one type of food or to a specific calorie count. You also need to look at the patient, for a 800lb patient has a much larger reservoir.   If a normal person did not eat for 300 days they would be dead, your body would literally run out of calories to operate.

Comment: @john Agreed, but in this particular case it seems the only calories taken were those forming part of the glucose tolerance tests required during fasting. The patient was 456lb at the start but OP didn't give any restrictions on starting weight. It is an unusual case, but that's why they wrote it up as a paper (and presumably why it was entered into the Guinness book of records). The full text is available at the link I posted above.

Comment: Depending on the weight of an individual, about 3 weeks or longer. Sugar will not ward off starvation.